# FindBugs in Intellij Idea doesn't refresh the result

Tags: intellij-idea, findbugs

Intellij Idea - version 14.1.3. Installed Findbugs plugin (v.0.9.997) and run once.
After fixing found bugs, I run it again but unfortunately the plugin still shows the same list of errors, ignoring my changes. Some of errors even point to the nonexisting lines (which I deleted).
Tried to invalidate IDE cache (with restarting), nevertheless it didn't help.

Could you please assist?

Comment: Have you compiled the project after fixing the problems? (Findbugs inspects the class files).

Comment: That's unbelievable! Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike IntelliJ IDEA's built in inspections, FindBugs uses the class files to find problems, not the source files. Make sure you compile your project after fixing the problems, otherwise FindBugs will keep seeing the problems in the out-of-date class files.